# Post request download in webview , but how to download file?

Tags: android, html, webview, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I want to enable post request downloads in webview (Just like chrome does)

How can i do it?i had tried many solutions but no one worked.

My goal is to save the file when 'POST' request triggered by any website. help with code tutorial

Comment: Its not duplicate post

Comment: you actually want to download the file from some path right?

Comment: I not understood

Comment: Do you want to download files from a specific path to the folder?

Comment: That will i can manage to place file in folder , juat receive receive response file from POST request i want (that chrome does) @rNkL.rG